# Is there any way to validate events payload schema while using Azure Event Hub API?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, json-schema-validator

I must send events to Azure Event Hub directly using http protocol. How can I validate payload json schema of the event in Azure (same as validating in a web api) before the event ingestion?

Comment: Are you worried that you'll be posting bad data? Or that once you've shipped the packet to Event Hub you'd like to run additional validation?

Comment: Yes, I  want to reject requests with bad data. Imagine a scenario where a third party send events to my Event Hub and I don't want to consume resources capturing them if they contain bad data.

Answer (score 1):

Inspection of event payloads and indexing are not within the feature scope of Event Hubs (or Apache Kafka).
See the Note Section here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-retention